# check for last index of last alphabet in a line in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755
```

In the above line, I want to find the index of the Last alphabet in a line as 'A' is the last alphabet in the string and I want to find the index of it in string.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: quick answer using the link posted as duplicate : `var="95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755"; var2="${var%[: alpha :]*}"; echo $((${#var2}-1))`

Comment: apart from adding what you've tried (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ) , you should also post expected output... like you want `26` or `25`, what if line has no alphabet, are there multiple lines in input and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
$ str="95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755"
$ echo $str | fold -w 1 | awk '/[a-zA-Z]/{x=NR}END{print x}'
26
$
```

`fold` will wrap the line depending on the width, in this case 1, which means every character will be in a new line. Using `awk`, we search for a character and assign the line number(`NR`) to the variable `x`, and print `x` at the end which should contain the index of the last character.

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(sed -r 's/(^.*)([[:alpha:]])([[:blank:]][[:digit:]]+$)/\2/' <<< "95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755")

awk -v let=$var '{ print index($0,toupper(let)) }' <<< "95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755"
```

First use sed with regular expressions to extract the second extracted separated single letter and read this into the variable var. Use var in awk to set the variable let using the index function to attain the index of the letter in the string.

Comment: Your solution prints `1` as answer.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the question. I have amended the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755' | grep -o '.*[a-zA-Z]' | tr -d '\n' | wc -c
```

Explanation:

`echo '95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755'` - Echoes your string

`grep -o '.*[a-zA-Z]'` -
The `.*` in grep will greedily match as many characters as possibly, and the `[a-zA-Z]` will match the final letter. The `-o` flag will tell grep to only print the matched characters. For your example, this will be `95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA`

`tr -d '\n'` - Deletes the new line character from the result of grep, to avoid overcounting by one

`wc -c` - Counts the number of characters.

Comment: or you can use `echo ... | grep -o '.*[a-zA-Z]' | awk '{print length()}'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try simple and easy approach as follows and let me know if this helps you.

```
echo "95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755" | awk '{match($0,/.*[a-zA-Z]/);print index($0,substr($0,RLENGTH,1))}'
```

OR

```
echo "95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755" | awk '{match($0,/.*[a-zA-Z]/);print RLENGTH}'
```

Comment: I think you may print `RLENGTH` directly.

Comment: @CWLiu, thanks I added that too in solution now :)

Comment: It's even simpler and easier than you think :-). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45311075/1745001

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755' | awk '{n=split($0,a,"");while(n--){ if(a[n]~/[A-Za-z]/){print a[n],n; break }}}'
A 26
```

**Better Readable**

```
awk '{
           n=split($0,a,"");
           while(n--)
           { 
             if(a[n]~/[A-Za-z]/)
             {
                print a[n],n;     # a[n] gives alphabet, n gives index
                break 
             }
           }
      }'
```

> Note that the standards say that the results are unspecified if an
>   empty string is assigned to `FS`. Some versions of `awk` will produce the
>   output, may not work in `OS X`

**OR Setting `FS=`**

```
$ echo '95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755' | awk -v FS= '{i=NF; while(i--)if($i~/[A-Za-z]/){print $i,i; break}}'
A 26
```

**Better Readable**

```
awk -v FS= '{
                i=NF; 
                while(i--)
                if($i~/[A-Za-z]/)
                {
                    print $i,i; break
                }
            }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755' |
    awk '{print match($0,/[[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*$/)}'
26
```